# Facing issue in setting the XY position of the Panel

Tags: extjs

I have a panel in which I'm adding multiple items(panels) and storing the height, width, xposition, yposition of each item in a store.

While initializing the panel adding items to the panel using store ( in which i have added items ). I'm able to show all the items which i have saved. But I'm facing issue with positions..

I used `item.getPosition()[0]` as **x** position and `item.getPosition()[1]` as **y** position.

and while adding items setting the position using `item.setPosition( pos.x,pos.y )`. But still I'm not able to get the items in exact positions same as i have saved.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks & Regards
URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some days ago using ExtJS 3.4 and after researchig on stackoverflow and on [sencha foruns](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?113328-Panel-Positioning-using-setPosition-after-Move-Event.) I found out that "Panels are not absolutely positioned by default, so cannot have their position set."

However you can do it using the `floating: true` config for the panel. Then it will behave as an independent panel, having absolute positioning. And so your code will probably work.

Note: To disable the `shadow` rendering of the floating panel(default behavior), use `floating: {shadow: false}` instead.